# How to prevent a folder from remaining after switching branches?

Tags: git

When I switch from `Master` to an earlier `1.0.0` branch, a folder that exists in `Master` stays behind.

I can add it to `.gitignore`, but that doesn't prevent it from remaining behind it. I can also run `git clean -f -d`, but this is more of a reactive fix.

I would like to know, how do I configure my environment so that git knows that when I switch from `Master` to `1.0.0`, it automatically removes the folder that doesn't also exist in `1.0.0`?

Comment: A `post-checkout` hook might work

Comment: Git typically deletes a directory if (and only if) it deletes the last file *in* that directory. It *cannot* delete a non-empty directory, so if you have something that creates files there (such as MacOS finder leaving `.DS_Store` junk files), you would have to remove those yourself. In the bad old days of Git 1.5 I used to see it leave empty directories at times and never tracked down when that occurred, but I have not seen it lately.

Comment: @torek The folder in question is a folder that exists and is committed to the `Master` branch, but did not exists and is not committed to the 1.0.0 branch. IIRC, git does a pretty good job of cleaning up other folders in the same project that exist in one branch but not in another, but this folder, in particular, might be missing a configuration somewhere for git to know to clean it up. AFAIK, I didn't have to do anything special with the other folders that exist in one branch but not the other for it to work properly.

Comment: "a [directory] that ... is committed": there *is no such thing*. Git does not store directories (aka folders). Git stores only files (which Git calls "blobs"), via pathnames recorded under what Git calls "trees" (this is the closest thing Git has to directories). When Git needs to name a file `foo/bar/baz` it will make directories `foo` and `bar` if and as needed. When Git removes the last file from `foo/bar` it will remove directory `bar` as well. And [continued]

Comment: ... switching from one branch to another is not particularly interesting here: it's switching *commits* that makes Git act, comparing our current *index* (which represents what Git has checked out right now) to the *target commit* (where we are asking Git to move to—this might be an old commit, or the tip commit of some other branch, or the tip of the *current* branch if we moved to an old commit earlier). Whatever paths are in the index now, but not the target commit, Git must remove. Whatever paths are there but not in the index, Git must create. Where blobs differ, Git must replace files.

Comment: @torek Thank you for clarifying that folders are not committed and that files contain metadata which generates trees which simulate folder structures. Since you know a lot more, do you have an idea how to resolve this? The folder contains files that belong to the `Master` branch, but not to the `1.0.0` branch. When I do a `git checkout 1.0.0`, the folder remains. It wouldn't be clean to add it to the `.gitignore` for the `1.0.0` branch. Alternatively, I could create a `post-checkout githook`, but that seems like I'm reacting to the issue, rather than fixing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure why the directory is not being removed, although if you are on a Mac and you use the Finder, that's probably why. (In which case a post-checkout hook might be the way to go.)

Comment: Thank you for your help @torek. Agreed, sounds like post-checkout hook will have to do.